# Laravel 5.4 go live with no npm installed

Tags: laravel-5, npm, vuejs2

I've just finished my first project with laravel.

Now when I want to go live, I suddenly discovered that my host does not allow installation of nodejs on their shard host package.

The shock the horror....

I managed to do everything on the live server, I ran npm run production on my local machine and uploaded the minified files for the css and js.

The problem is, on my shard server, I still get this vue warning:

> You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on
>   production mode when deploying for production. See more tips at
>   https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

but not on my local machine.

Looking at the link they refer to, I don't really understand what I need to do as I'm new to laravel, npm, node and vue.

How can I turn vue to production mode manually without npm?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can adjust this manually. If you are using the Laravel scaffolding for Laravel Mix, add the following lines to your **resources/js/bootstrap.js** file

```
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.debug = false
Vue.config.silent = true
```

These lines will suppress the warnings, debugging and turn off devtools, essentially the same as ***npm run production***. This will also turn them off in your local environment, but it is probably your only solution.